# info on javascript document.createElement()

Tags: javascript, html

How do I create the following markup using JavaScript's `document.createElement` function?

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="" />
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is some code to create your input box:

```
var element = document.createElement('input');
element.type = 'hidden';
element.value = '';
element.id = '';
```

To add it to a `<form>` with `id="myform"` you could do this:

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
myform.appendChild(element);
```

FYI: Your `<input>` doesn't have a `name` attribute. If you're planning on submitting it as part of a form and processing it on the server side, you should probably include one.

Answer (score 7):

Using DOM methods:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("value", "");
input.setAttribute("id", "");

document.getElementById("the-form-id").appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 3):

Empty values, here, are equal to not setting them, so i won't:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';

document.body.appendChild(input); // or append it anywhere else...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputTag  = document.createElement("input");
inputTag.type = "hidden";
```

It's not necessary to set the other two properties since they would start as nothing anyway.