# How to get values on ashx page submitted from javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have one aspx page from which I am posting form like

```
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
            form.setAttribute("action", '/my.ashx');

            var field = document.createElement("input");
            field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            field.setAttribute("name", 'myVal');
            field.setAttribute("value", "1234627373737377");
            form.appendChild(field);

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
```

And I am trying to access myVal on my.ashx page by using 
var myValue= context.Request["myVal"]; but I am getting null value.

Comment: `setAttribute` smells fishy to me. I would try setting properties directly like in the following examples. 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086718/info-on-javascript-document-createelement 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991204/how-to-create-a-form-dynamically-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this on .ashx page:

```
HtmlInputHidden input = PreviousPage.FindControl("myVal") as HtmlInputHidden;
string previousValue = input.Value;
```

include the assembly reference on the top of the page:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

Although not tested, but hope it would work.

Comment: showing error that 'Previous Page' does not exist in the current context

Comment: if you can change the technique slightly? instead of creating the hidden input type, place the input element in the page html. then test if it works? `<input type="hidden" name="myVal" id="myVal" value="1234" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myValue = context.Request.Form["myVal"]
```

**Udpated:**

You're missing an attribute with form `form.setAttribute("enctype", 'multipart/form-data');` with out setting it your Form variable in `Request` will not be populated.

Comment: used this Still not working var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("enctype", 'multipart/form-data');
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                form.setAttribute("action", '/my.ashx');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'myVal');
                field.setAttribute("value", "1234567890");
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit()

Comment: Try debug in your handler when receiving the request. Check if your request have Form property initialized. Rest looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this while submitting: `field.setAttribute("id", 'myVal');`

And access it like: `myValue = context.Request.Form["myVal"]`