# How can I create HTML tags using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, canvas

I have this code that I want to create using JavaScript since I will be using it in more than one file.
I thought about using :after with CSS but it didn't work.
Then I thought about using the DOM manipulation to create the HTML tags but I couldn't get it done.

can anyone help me?

The image below illustrate what I am trying to accomplish

1. the main div tag
2. the div tag inside main div tag
3. the div tags I want to create using JavaScript

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Thanks everybody for the help. Here is what I got from your response

```
//CREATE MENU DIVs

    const mainbody = document.querySelector('body') //or target div

    const divbtn = document.createElement('div');
    divbtn.setAttribute('id','btn');

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'https://thiagoprado.com/demo/learning/overlay-menu.png');
    img.setAttribute('id','menu');
    img.style.display = "block";

    const img2 = document.createElement('img');
    img2.setAttribute('src', 'https://thiagoprado.com/demo/learning/close-menu.png');
    img2.setAttribute('id','x');
    img2.style.display = "none";

    divbtn.appendChild(img);
    divbtn.appendChild(img2);
    //canvasDIV.appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById("c2canvasdiv").appendChild(divbtn);


    // second main DIV

    const divbox = document.createElement('div');
    divbox.setAttribute('id','box');

    const divItems = document.createElement('div');
    divItems.setAttribute('id','items');

    const divItem = document.createElement('div');
    divItem.setAttribute('class','item');

    const divItem2 = document.createElement('div');
    divItem2.setAttribute('class','item');
    //divItem2.setAttribute('id','item2');

    const link1 = document.createElement('a');
    link1.setAttribute('href','https://thiagoprado.com/demo/learning/');

    const img3 = document.createElement('img');
    img3.setAttribute('src', 'https://thiagoprado.com/demo/learning/home-60x60.png');


    const link2 = document.createElement('a');
    link2.setAttribute('href','#');

    const img4 = document.createElement('img');
    img4.setAttribute('src', 'https://thiagoprado.com/demo/learning/logo-60x60.png');

    divbox.appendChild(divItems);
    divItems.appendChild(divItem);
    divItem.appendChild(link1);
    link1.appendChild(img3);

    divItems.appendChild(divItem2);
    divItem2.appendChild(link2);
    link2.appendChild(img4);        

    document.getElementById("c2canvasdiv").appendChild(divbox);
```

Comment: DOM manipulation is the correct way. Have you done any research on *how to create  HTML elements in JavaScript*?

Comment: *but I couldn't get it done*. How come? Could you show us what you've tried and what went wrong? Edit your question and add your JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [info on javascript document.createElement()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086718/info-on-javascript-document-createelement)

Comment: NB: most of the time you don't need to call `.setAttribute`, you can do e.g. `link2.href = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the javascript you are looking for.
a small example of creating elements via js. by reading this. you should be able to accomplish what you want.

```
const root = document.querySelector('body') //or target div
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "text for div";
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'urlString');
div.setAttribute('id','box');

div.appendChild(img);
root.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: -1 you should use `Element.textContent` to add text content not `innerHTML`. You only use setAttribute for properties not defined by DOM and then only if you want the attribute to be parsed. `id` and `src` are already defined in the DOM there is no need to use `setAttribute` to change the values. Nor do you need to query for body it is a property of document  eg `document.body.appendChild`

Comment: I would ask that you remove that -1: the set attribute is 100% correct if you are generating the elements in js... (he's not editing them via javascript, but creating them, so nothing has been defined). the query was to show how to append/grab things defined already. 
the above was just an example to the relevant code.
although I agree with the textContent in general: innerHTML is useful to know about.

Comment: ?? not editing them?? I do not see the distinction between creation and editing.  DOM properties are always defined eg `document.createElement('div').id === ""` is true  (same for img src) If they were not defined they would equal undefined  `document.createElement('div').randomProp === undefined` is true. .100% not sure what that means. All things equal the simplest is always preferred `document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {textContent: "hello world", id: "box"})));`

Comment: const javascriptCREATEDELEMENT = document.createElement("div");
``````
console.log(javascriptCREATEDELEMENT.id) //undefined.
```````
javascriptCREATEDELEMENT.setAttribute("id", "test");
````````
console.log(javascriptCREATEDELEMENT.id) //test.
`````

Comment: he's not asking to target the elements in existance - (and therefore has props like id) but how to generate it soley though js... so you need to set the attributes of those elements in js with setAttribute.

Comment: you generally don't modify DOM elements with = operator. but with the method used for setting attributes... all attributes. setAttribute();

Comment: You wrote *"console.log(document.createElement("div").id) //undefined."* what browser are you using. `console.log(document.createElement("div").id === "");//true` and `console.log(document.createElement("div").id === undefined); // false`. Set and Get attribute only for undefined properties that need parsing, or undefined properties you want to appear in the markup. And *"...generally don't modify DOM elements with ="* and by generally you mean.....?

Comment: I mean. setAttribute(). is for all Attributes. not just undefined/custom attributes ('which as far as I understand (have to or generally) start with "data-" ')
element.setAttribute('class', 'elementClass'); is also 100% valid.
setAttribute() and getAttribute() are better than element[attribute] = value. methods instead of accessing the props directly.

Comment: I think I got it. I need to polish a little bit but the hard part is done. It is not pretty but it works

Comment: All defined DOM properties are read from and written to via getters and setters (therefor what needs to be done will be done).  Incorrectly using set/getAttribute will get a -1 every time.Why...The last browser that required the set/getAttribute call for DOM properties was Netscape navigator. Holding on to an ideal that originated during the browser wars of the late 90's, and by pushing it's (set/getAttribute) unwarranted use  only perpetuates a concept that became old 20+ years ago and needs to be stamped out.

Comment: okay. so you are saying setAttribute and getAttribute WILL NOT work? how? what behavior will fail when using the prescribed set and get?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: the docs say nothing about those methods being depreciated, or warn of any failures.
nor do they warn or indicate a better pattern to use instead.



I think you THINK it 'better'. but you haven't described any benefit from going about it any other way? so it comes to a matter of personal choice? and your opinion is worth more than mine apparently.

Comment: you say it is 'incorrect' but the docs back me up... so what is incorrect about using setAttribute() to SET THE ATTRIBUTE of an element. (defined attribute or not: setAttribute() works regardless)? I REALLY DON'T UNDERSTAND what you are saying? how would you set the id of an element that is defined in JS as 'div'... would you just say div.id = "whatever"? as opposed to div.setAttribute('id', 'whatever')? why?

Comment: Why! because simpler is always the preferred method when all things are equal.

Comment: simpler is setAttribute, and getAttribute.


el.attribute = value does not work for all possible values.

setAttribute() and getAttribute(). work for ALL attributes. I agree with KISS. keep it simple, stupid. this is the simplest and most holistic method for accessing and setting attributes and properties on the DOM.

Comment: Using a function call directly to assign a basic property in a modern language, with getters and setters and a spec sheet ten miles long, its done automatically why draw out the verbosity, turning good code in to an unreadable mess....  Oh well we all have our styles. Thank you for the debate but will stop now and agree to disagree

Comment: agree to disagree. consistency and readability is king. that's why I use the only method that works for all attributes. rather than do different things for exactly the same task.

Answer (score 2):

### Dynamic HTML

DOM manipulation via javascript is the quickest way to generate dynamic content, however it can be exceedingly verbose and thus hard to read, maintain, and keep free of bugs.

When you write code you should always be thinking about keeping the code [D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#:%7E:text=The%20DRY%20principle%20is%20stated,their%20book%20The%20Pragmatic%20Programmer.)

Your code example has 42 lines, 12 temp variables. Looking at it in a glance it gives no clue to the structure you are creating. And what if there is a design changes, that's a lot of work if you come back in a month and make changes.

- Use functions to do repetitive tasks
- Think about how you can structure you data so its easy to extract information from it.
- Avoid bad coding habits.

### Example

Using DRY principles

- Creating 3 functions for common tasks create, append and query,
- Storing the url base in a variable (avoiding chance of typo when entering long strings)
- Structuring the code such that it reflect what it is creating

The result is more code of better quality in less time.

The following does exactly the same as you code example.

```
const url = "https://thiagoprado.com/demo/learning/";
const element = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
const append = (par, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((p, sib) => (p.appendChild(sib), p), par);
const queryEl = (qStr, el = document) => el.querySelector(qStr);

append(queryEl("#c2canvasdiv"),
  append(element("div", {id: "btn"}),
    element("img", {id: "menuEl", src: url + "overlay-menu.png", className: "block"}),
    element("img", {id: "closeEl", src: url + "close-menu.png", className: "hide"}),
  ),
  append(element("div", {id: "box"}),
    append(element("div", {id: "items"}),
      append(element("div", {className: "item"}),
        append(element("a", {href: url}), element("img", {src: url + "home-60x60.png"}))
      )
    ),
    append(element("div", {className: "item"}),
      append(element("a", {href: "#"}), element("img", {src: url + "logo-60x60.png"}))
    )
  )
);
```

Oh and CSS rules as in-lining styles are a very bad habit

```
.hide {display: none}
.block {display: block}
```

<sub>P.S don't use `setAttribute` if you don't need to</sub>

Comment: Great solution. I liked the level of sophistication. I will definitely bookmark it for future use.

Answer (score -1):

Use document.createElement, assign with innerHTML and ID and finally append node to parent element.

https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_document_createelement.asp