# Trying to create custom HTML nodes with javascript for page injection

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

Currently I am trying to inject some HTML onto Youtube's Page with a chrome extension that I am working on. They use custom HTML on their page and so I am creating custom DOM Nodes like theirs.

```js
  const channelSection = document.createElement("ytd-rich-section-renderer");
```

However, when I execute the above node I do not see my injected HTML anywhere on the page. To bug test this, I instead switched out the tag name for a basic `div` tag and it worked then.

For reference, I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html) other stackoverflow question to accomplish my goal. Thanks for the help!

Edit:
Thanks for all the responses! So after reloading the extension a couple of times, I can actually see my custom HTML injected in the page via the console.

`content.js`

```js
  const ce = function(tag) {
        return document.createElement(tag)
     }
  const channelSection = ce("ytd-rich-section-renderer");
  channelSection.classList.add("style-scope", "ytd-rich-grid-renderer");

  let content = ce("div");
  content.classList.add("style-scope", "ytd-rich-section-renderer");

  let subContent = ce("ytd-rich-shelf-renderer");
  subContent.classList.add("style-scope", "ytd-rich-section-renderer");

  let dismiss = ce("div");
  dismiss.setAttribute("id", "dismissable");
  dismiss.classList.add("style-scope", "ytd-rich-shelf-renderer");

  // Heading
  let richShelf = ce("div");
  richShelf.setAttribute("id", "rich-shelf-header");
  richShelf.classList.add("style-scope", "ytd-rich-shelf-renderer");

  // Put Cards In here
  let contents = ce("div");
  contents.setAttribute("id", "contents");
  contents.classList.add("style-scope", "ytd-rich-shelf-renderer");

  dismiss.appendChild(richShelf);
  dismiss.appendChild(contents);
  subContent.appendChild(dismiss);
  content.appendChild(subContent);
  channelSection.appendChild(content);

  // This works
  let mainPage = document.querySelector("#contents");
      mainPage.prepend(channelSection);
```

Now my main issue that is I only see the `channelSection` and `content` nodes on the page. Am I appending the DOM nodes incorrectly possibly?

Comment: can you please post the complete relevant code?

Comment: You're creating the element...where are you adding it to your page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [info on javascript document.createElement()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086718/info-on-javascript-document-createelement)

Comment: Now that you solved your initial question, mark the relevant answer as a solution and ask a new question. Don't transmogrify your original question into a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method creates a [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element) and stores it in the variable, it is not inserted into the DOM, you have to do it manually, using appending methods like:

- [ParentNode.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append): inserts the Node after the last child of the Parent Node.

Note that when you create a custom HTML Tag, you will get a [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) which derives from the [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) interface and does not implement any additional properties or methods.

I recommend you to use the [Template tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) to create the node you want to insert to make your code more readable, example:

```
function htmlToElement(html) {
    var template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return template.content.firstChild;
}
```

You can use like this:

```
var myContent =  htmlToElement('<div class="my-class"><div class="mychild-class"></div><span id="my-span"></span></div>');
//Getting an element inside the created node
var mySpan = myContent.querySelector("#my-span");
```